# Kotlin call overloaded function by parameter type (when only interface type is known)

Tags: kotlin

Our codebase has an interface with a large number of implementations. These are serialized, stored, and deserialized. When one is deserialized, we call a function that takes the interface type, which then has a giant when clause that branches based on the specific type, i.e.

```
   when (t) {
      is SubType1 -> ...
      is SubType2 -> ...
      is SubType44 -> ...
   }
```

This is gross and adds high complexity to the function. One possibility is to move the action that we want to perform to the actual implementations themselves, so we can just call t.doAction(), and eliminate the when clause. That's OK, but this particular logic doesn't really belong on the implementations (for reasons), so it'd be nicer to be able to call parameter type overloaded functions instead, and have kotlin figure out which to call based on the implementation type. Unfortunately it doesn't seem able to; we get "None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied."

Is there a pattern here that we could leverage that'd satisfy the compiler?

Contrived example below. i1 is an Int under the hood, but the compiler's unable to see that because it is typed as the interface, i.e. Number.

```
    fun test() {
        val e = Example()

        val i1 = 123 as Number
        val i2 = 123.0

        e.sqrt(i1)
        e.sqrt(i2)
    }

    class Example {

        fun sqrt(i: Int) {

        }

        fun sqrt(i: Double) {

        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how the example (if it could work) would be any less gross than the `when` block.

Comment: Could you expand on the reasons you don't want to put the logic inside the SubType classes? I assume you used "doAction()" to be an easier to understand example, but what method name would "doAction()" be if you were to include it as part of the interface?

Comment: @Tenfour04 better unit testability. It's much more obvious just looking at the function whether all branches have been covered.

Comment: @Aro some (e.g. Yegor Bugayenko) would argue that objects should own all of behavior that relates to them. In this case we're building something derived from the objects that isn't really a core behavior or property of them. Pragmatically I'm not opposed to it living there, but it has a slight smell to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a disicion map. The function will stay the same with new implementations and only the map will get bigger:

```
val map : Map<KClass<*>, (Any) -> Unit> = mapOf(
  SubType1::class to { /*SubType1 implementation*/ },
  SubType2::class to { /*SubType2 implementation*/ },
  ...
)

fun <T> execute(item: T) {

  map[item::class]?.invoke(item) ?: error("Case not implemented")

}
```

If you have many lines of implementation per case and/or you want to test elegantly, you may create a class for each case and test it seperately:

```
interface ClassDesicion<T> {
   fun execute(item: T) : Unit
}

val map : Map<KClass<*>, ClassDesicion<*>> = mapOf(
  SubType1::class to SubType1Implementation(),
  SubType2::class to SubType2Implementation(),
  ...
)
```